# Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer/Errors'. How to fix?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using the below code for Puppeteer to do something if timeout error occurs:

```
const {TimeoutError} = require('puppeteer/Errors');

try {
  await page.waitForSelector(yourSelector, {timeout: 5000});
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TimeoutError) {
    // Do something if this is a timeout.
  }
}
```

In theory it should work, but it throws' an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer/Errors'
```

Not sure why is that?

Maybe I need to install this module ?

Need help desperately.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SORTED!

used this code instead (with `puppeteer.errors.TimeoutError` inside the code):

```
try {
  await page.waitForSelector('.foo');
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof puppeteer.errors.TimeoutError) {
    // Do something if this is a timeout.
  }
}
```

looks like

```
const {TimeoutError} = require('puppeteer/Errors');
```

is for older Puppeteer versions.